# locking on object don't stop on changes from other Thread

Tags: java, concurrency

i'v tried to make a lock on object but with no result

how to handle lock in this case ?

[image]

EDIT:

Based  on  comments  I decided  not  to  post question  with  code anymore.  It's  not about  to  copy  and  paste  then  run  and  check  what  compiler  says.

Instead of focusing on the issue you create artificially a problem rather than face this one which I'm facing.

Instead of synchronized block maybe I should use the lock for writing or re entrant lock...

Do I required  "hand-over-hand" or "chain locking"?

or even  use semaphore?

**EDIT2:**

**what i have:**

- i got **object A** which **holds refrence to X** and got **method getX**(return X) & **reset**X(X=null)
- i got **object X** with **fields a,b,c**

**what i do:**

other thread T:

- takes reference to  X via _x = A.getX()
- do some stuff change _x.a
- do some stuff change _x.c
- /// **in meanwhile A decides to reset X**  ///
- do some stuff change _x.b
  ... crash !

**what i want to achieve:**

- prevent A.resetX(null) while T is modyfiing X(_x)

in  other words to prevent object = null while there are modification to object in progress

do i need to use **some flag indicating** that **X** is **under modification**?

**what i don't want:**

- constantly checks **if(X!=null)**

**AND:**

> @downvoter: Care to explain your vote! please

Comment: @Codebender I agree with you. Although, this is not a bad way to explain the problem. :)

Comment: @TomaszBest: So take that skeleton and put it as code, not as image,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OK! I've dug enough information to get solution for my case:**

best way here is to use

> **interface ReadWriteLock** provided by package **java.util.concurrent.locks**

together with implementation of:

> **ReentrantReadWriteLoc**

**here is "simple" sample example:**

```
/**
 * define modifiable dog
 */
public class Dog {

    private ReadWriteLock _dogLock;
    private String _name;

    public Dog(ReadWriteLock dogLock) {
        _dogLock = dogLock;
    }

    public Lock dogChangesLock() {
        return _dogLock.writeLock();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        _dogLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            _name = name;
        } finally {
            _dogLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        _dogLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            return _name;
        } finally {
            _dogLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * holder class for dog handling
 */
public class Holder {

    private Dog _dog;

    /**
     * EURECA! this is what we want to use
     */
    private ReadWriteLock _dogLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    /**
     * get dog
     */
    public Dog getDog() {
        _dogLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            if (_dog == null) {
                _dog = new Dog(_dogLock);
            }
            return _dog;
        } finally {
            _dogLock.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * utilize dog :)
     */
    private void resetDog() {
        _dogLock.readLock().lock();
        try {
            _dog = null;
        } finally {
            _dogLock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * test class for simultaneous write/read
 */
public class Concurent {

    Holder holder = new Holder();

    /**
     * run concurrent threads
     */
    private void test() {

        /** thread for dog modification */
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            /** thread to utilize dog :) */
            final Thread resetThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    holder.resetDog();
                }
            });

            /** main method */
            @Override
            public void run() {

                /** get dog */
                Dog dog = holder.getDog();

                /** get lock for write */
                dog.dogChangesLock().lock();

                try {

                    /** modifies dog */
                    dog.setName("Cat");

                    /** call to reset dog */
                    resetThread.start();

                    /**
                     * SAFE TO CALL SECOND TIME 
                     * we don't need to check if dog was altered 
                     * as we got write lock 
                     * */
                    dog.setName("Elephant");

                } finally {
                    dog.dogChangesLock().unlock();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```